# Visual studio Express 2013 is not showing web templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just installed visual studio 2013 on windows 8.1

When i go to new project then in the windows visual studio is not showing web templates like web pages, MVC 3,4,5 and other stuff like Windows form application and data bases. Visual studio is just showing phone apps development templates. why is this so because i have installed visual studio express with update 2 and i think its latest.

I tried many things like repairing update 2 and installed other asp.net templates for visual studio 2013 but i am not getting on my way...

Please suggest me solutions

Comment: It doesn't necessarily look the same as VS 2010 or VS 2012 .  Have you looked at this article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started if so are you saying you can't see the Web Template folder or the ASP .NET Web Application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Express* versions of Visual Studio come in flavors for desktop and web.  It sounds like you might want [Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).  If you want the more *full featured* version, check out the [commercial versions here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-with-msdn-overview-vs#AdditionalPageSections_1).

There's also a few ways to get the commercial versions for free.  If you're a small company, check out the [BizSpark program](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/).  If you're a student, check out the [DreamSpark program](https://www.dreamspark.com/).

Comment: yes i installed microsoft visual studio express 2013 for windows,Is there is any way so that i can install web module in the existing visual studio.

Comment: Hmm not that i know of..  I think you need to uninstall and reinstall..  Though you might be able to have both installed at the same time, i haven't tried that..

Comment: I don't think so, i think you'll need to install it seperately...which is a pain

Comment: what will be the difference b/w express edition and professional edition.. professional will have both modules..?

Comment: @MudasirRao - Correct, the commercial versions can handle solutions with all the project types.  Express also lacks a lot of features, and support for plugins.  [Here's a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) of the limitations.  But hey, Express is free so you can't complain too much :)

Comment: In short you are trying to say that to have all features of windows and web i must install professional edition.

Comment: Is it possible the install the Windows and Web express both in same system ?

Answer (score 0):

Both Web and Desktop can be installed at the same time. I have both installed on my Windows Server 2012 Box