# Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop doesn't have the tag Web - ASP.NET Empty Web Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new with C# and a want to create a web application on visual studio. But it doesn't appear the tag "Web". I need to install something?
[image]

Thank's

Comment: Check this [Visual studio Express 2013 is not showing web templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941336/visual-studio-express-2013-is-not-showing-web-templates)

Comment: If you are just starting out (so you have no baggage of existing code), you might want to use Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition in stead. That version doesn't have the arbitrary web<->desktop split the old Express versions had.